# Populating Textbox With Current Directory

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am writing a winform in C# and I have a textbox beside a combobox that displays the selection made.  The combo box is for selecting the directory in which to save a file and I would like to populate the textbox with the current directory as a default.  Here is the code I am using that is not working:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox4.Text = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You want the directory that the app is running within?

Comment: I think the GetCurrentDirectory() routine already returns a string, why convert it to string again?

Comment: `It's not working`, you are a little vague here... probably an explanation of what is not working will be beneficial

Comment: By not working I mean that the textbox is empty.

Comment: Your line of code is correct and works i.e. 
textBox4.Text = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint on that line (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) and run the app. Do your app  stop there?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the `Form1_Load` event handler never gets called. Try setting a breakpoint at that function, and see if it ever gets called.

You could also place this line in the form constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   textBox4.Text = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
}
```

This method of getting the current directory (using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`) is correct, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes your right @Tibi thats what is happening.... I just removed the binding for Form_Load event and the textbox is empty

Comment: Thanks, but the text box is still empty.  @HatSoft: I'm going to go back through my old questions as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: So even though you placed the instruction in the constructor, it is still not working? Try setting textBox4.Text = "Hello world", see if that works. Maybe it's the wrong textbox, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done something similar but with an open file dialog.  I was after the full path.  I used the following.  The Path.GetFullPath returns the full path of the file.  It's part of the System.IO namespace.

```
textboxPath = Path.GetFullPath(opendialog.FileName);
```